# bloomberg can't start session

Tags: java, bloomberg

I am using bloomberg API to fetch market data, this is example given with the API SDK

```
package blpapi;

import com.bloomberglp.blpapi.CorrelationID;
import com.bloomberglp.blpapi.Element;
import com.bloomberglp.blpapi.Event;
import com.bloomberglp.blpapi.Message;
import com.bloomberglp.blpapi.MessageIterator;
import com.bloomberglp.blpapi.Name;
import com.bloomberglp.blpapi.Request;
import com.bloomberglp.blpapi.Service;
import com.bloomberglp.blpapi.Session;
import com.bloomberglp.blpapi.SessionOptions;

public class SimpleRefDataExample {
    private static final Name SECURITY_DATA = new Name("securityData");
    private static final Name SECURITY = new Name("security");
    private static final Name FIELD_DATA = new Name("fieldData");
    private static final Name FIELD_EXCEPTIONS = new Name("fieldExceptions");
    private static final Name FIELD_ID = new Name("fieldId");
    private static final Name ERROR_INFO = new Name("errorInfo");
    private CorrelationID d_cid;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleRefDataExample example = new SimpleRefDataExample();
        example.run(args);
        System.out.println("Press ENTER to quit");
        System.in.read();
    }

    private void run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String serverHost = "localhost";
        int serverPort = 35230;

        SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions();
        sessionOptions.setServerHost(serverHost);
        sessionOptions.setServerPort(serverPort);

        Session session = new Session(sessionOptions);

        System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverHost + ":" + serverPort);
        if (!session.start()) {
            System.err.println("Failed to start session.");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Connected successfully.");

        if (!session.openService("//blp/refdata")) {
            System.err.println("Failed to open //blp/refdata");
            return;
        }

        Service refDataService = session.getService("//blp/refdata");
        Request request = refDataService.createRequest("ReferenceDataRequest");

        // append securities to request
        Element securities = request.getElement("securities");
        securities.appendValue("IBM US Equity");
        securities.appendValue("/cusip/912828GM6@BGN");

        // append fields to request
        Element fields = request.getElement("fields");
        fields.appendValue("PX_LAST");
        fields.appendValue("DS002");

        System.out.println("Sending Request: " + request);
        d_cid = session.sendRequest(request, null);

        while (true) {
            Event event = session.nextEvent();
            MessageIterator msgIter = event.messageIterator();
            while (msgIter.hasNext()) {
                Message msg = msgIter.next();
                if (msg.correlationID() == d_cid) {
                    processMessage(msg);
                }
            }
            if (event.eventType() == Event.EventType.RESPONSE) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void processMessage(Message msg) throws Exception {
        Element securityDataArray = msg.getElement(SECURITY_DATA);
        int numSecurities = securityDataArray.numValues();
        for (int i = 0; i < numSecurities; ++i) {
            Element securityData = securityDataArray.getValueAsElement(i);
            System.out.println(securityData.getElementAsString(SECURITY));
            Element fieldData = securityData.getElement(FIELD_DATA);
            for (int j = 0; j < fieldData.numElements(); ++j) {
                Element field = fieldData.getElement(j);
                if (field.isNull()) {
                    System.out.println(field.name() + " is NULL.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(field);
                }
            }
            Element fieldExceptionArray =
                securityData.getElement(FIELD_EXCEPTIONS);
            for (int k = 0; k < fieldExceptionArray.numValues(); ++k) {
                Element fieldException =
                    fieldExceptionArray.getValueAsElement(k);
                System.out.println(
                        fieldException.getElement(ERROR_INFO).getElementAsString("category")
                        + ": " + fieldException.getElementAsString(FIELD_ID));
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

getting this error:

```
run:
Connecting to localhost:35230
Failed to start session.
Press ENTER to quit
```

local host is running on my system through xampp, I tried with default port : 8080, and without port also didn't worked, then I started glass fish server which was also working 
`http://localhost:35230`  but still getting this error what more configuration are required?

Comment: What product of BB are you using, Desktop or ServerAPI?

Answer (score 2):

The default port for the local `bbcomm` process is generally 8194. You need the `bbcomm.exe` process to be running and to be connected to Bloomberg via a Bloomberg terminal.

Comment: Hi I have running bbcomm.exe file then same problem also coming.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Desktop API, Bloomberg API does "Not" let you to connect to any other machine other than local host. This is by design.

As explained above the default port for DesktopAPI is 8194. Check the BBCOMM.CFG file to see if your are using  Port 8194.

Also run BBCOMM file directly from the command prompt to see if you get errors.

If you are using ServerAPI let me know...